# How to align td of my table with th?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, foreach

The table's first columns are personal data, the second part is about operations for employees. I want to create cells within the row. It works without conditional repeats of the data of all the employees, but if I put the condition it causes me this problem.
This information is part of the tr.

```
  <?php  
        if( !empty($obtOpera)) {
         foreach($obtOpera as $fi) { 
           if( !empty($consult) ) {
             foreach($consult as $fil) {
               if($fil->operation==$fi->operation && $fila->cveEmp ==$fil->cveEmp)  { 

                echo "<td class='$fil->color'<h4> $fil->operation</h4> X";
               }#Close if
            elseif ($fi->operation!=$fil->operation) {
             echo "<td>N/A</td>";

          }#Close Else if
        }#Close consult 
      }#Close if that compare operation
     }#Close foreach fi 
   }#Close if de obtOpera  ?>
```

Here image for table 
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqlr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here answer of my question:

```
<?php  
          if(!empty($obtOperation))
          {
           foreach($obtOperation as $fi) 
           { 
              $this->load->model('Reports_model');
              $fil=$this->Reports_model->consult($fil->idBlock, $date1, $date2, $fila->cveEmp, $fi->idOperation);

            if(!empty($fil))
            {
             foreach($fil as $fil) 
             {
               if($fi->idOperation==$fil->idOperation)
               { 
                 echo "<td class='$fil->color'><h4> $fil->operation</h4> X</td>";        
                }#close else                
           }#close consult 
         }
         else
         {
          echo "<td>N/A</td>";
          }#Close if 
        }#Close foreach fi 
    }#Closeif de obtOperation 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `</td>` in the foreach loop.

it should be:

```
echo "<td class='$fil->color'<h4> $fil->operation</h4> X</td>";
```

Comment: Yeah I do, but I continue with same problem, thank u :)